# What is the title of an anime with a bandaged guy with a look similar to Vampire Hunter D?

Tags: story-identification, anime

I was on the MRT a couple of days ago and this guy in front of me was watching an anime that seemed interesting.

The character style reminded me a lot of old 90s movies like Vampire Hunter D, with very strong detailed features.

One of the characters was a blonde guy with a huge mohawk and an excessive amount of muscles and he was fighting a guy that was completely bandaged up except for his eyes. There was some strange scene where the bandaged guy is shown on a shard of ice and it's dropped and shatters into a lot of pieces.

Does it ring any bells?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess it is jojo's bizarre adventure and the character could be Polnareff
[image: Polnareff]
Polnareff

[image: The other fighter:]
The other fighter

Comment: Any reason to believe so, could you provide more evidence of their similarity?

Comment: You guess?  Do you have anything to back that up?

Comment: Well i am sorry i am at work so i can't point out everything. But it is because he has a "huge mohawk" is a bit blond (well it is more like grey). And he fight a character which is inside mirror like things (things like a ice shard). :)

Answer (score 6):

The show Ruroni Kenshin is from the 90s, and had a character named Shishio who was as you describe, completely bandaged except for his eyes.  Is this the one you are thinking of?

[image: Image of Shishio]

Comment: Could you possibly add some of the information from the link in your answer? Any extra details really help OPs confirm an answer without having to go out of their way to confirm them.

Comment: That was just a link to an image of the character that matches the description given in the question.  I thought that would be the easiest way to tell.  I'll see if I can put the image directly in my answer.

Comment: Ah, I'll embed the image into the answer then! That's exactly the kind of information I suggested. There we go. Nice find!

Comment: @Edlothiad Thank you.  I'll see if I can find how to do that myself for next time.

Comment: You have two options, either add `![image description](hyperlink)` to the text, or the easy way is to simply click the picture button at the top (note links have to be https for them to be understood/translated onto slack)

Comment: Thank you for your help, this character also fits the description perfectly however it was not the right one :)