# Anime where a man shoots bullets controlled by small creatures

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm trying to find an anime in which guy is shooting a normal-looking revolver, but there are little creatures riding the bullets yelling and making the bullets bounce in crazy ways to shoot people.

Does anyone know which anime this is?

Comment: seems to be the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179867/what-is-the-title-of-an-anime-with-a-bandaged-guy-with-a-look-similar-to-vampire

Answer (score 3):

This would be *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure Part 5: Vento Aureo*, and the man with the gun is Guido Mista. In the *JoJo* universe, there are various characters with powers called "Stands", which manifest in the form of familiars. Mista's Stand, ["Sex Pistols"](http://jojo.fandom.com/wiki/Sex_Pistols), manifests in the form of six small creatures that ride on the bullets he fires, enabling him to control them in mid-air and pull off all kinds of trick shots.

[image]

Comment: https://jojo.fandom.com/wiki/Sex_Pistols is you want a wiki link. :) I was about to post.

Comment: Omg wonderful. been searching for this for a while

Comment: @KhariJGlover If this is correct, please accept it by clicking the green tick mark next to it.

Comment: The initial thread title had me thinking of Slugterra